# Merging audio streams with mismatched length to end together

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two mono audio files of (say) 60 seconds and 90 seconds length.

I want to mux the pair together into a stereo file (one in each channel) so that they end at the same time.

I can achieve this with the following merge filter which incorporates a delay at the start of the shortest file.

```
ffmpeg -i one.wav -i two.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]adelay=30s[1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp3
```

This works great **but** I have to pre-calculate the duration difference between the two channels in determining my delay - is there a way to just specify that the files should end together?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: I'd be more inclined to throw them both into a dedicated audio editor - even such as Audacity can do this kind of elementary task - line up the ends by eye/ear & save the result. Using ffmpeg for this kind of task always seems to be the equivalent of writing down the equation to catch a ball in the air, rather than just putting your hand out.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin - my use case involves phone calls and the ongoing programmatic reproduction of the task, so simplifying this automated step is the name of my game.